# Call function from different components and pass parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function Im calling several times when I need to process a date:

```
  dateFormat(myDate, format) {
    let temp=this.datePipe.transform(myDate, format)
    return(temp)
  }
```

This just formats a date.

```
let niceDate=dateFormat(mydate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

The problem is I need to call it from several components. I was looking at services it looks like its not what Im looking for (I may be wrong). Im wondering if this can be accomplished like in Node.js, but in Angular.

What is the right way to store several functions on one file, import that file and call the functions from other components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create common utility file in that you can implement those functions which are going to be used across the application. Now you just need to import that file any component and Use that static function.

For ex:
`Utils.ts` file

```
export class Utils {
    constructor() { }
    
    dateFormat(myDate, format) {
         let temp=this.datePipe.transform(myDate, format)
         return(temp)
    }
}
```

`component.ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Utils } from 'src/app/shared/utils/utils';

export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
       
       myDate = new Date();
       format = 'MM/DD/YYYY'
       
       constructor() { }
       
       covnervtDate(){
             return Utils.dateFormat(this.myDate, this.format);
       }
}
```

Comment: Thats the way I do it in Node, but the syntax is pretty different. I will try it right now.

Comment: Keval, Im getting "Property 'dateFormat' does not exist on type 'typeof Utils'" when calling dateformat at return Utils.dateFormat(date, format);

Comment: Hi @pvg1975, You need to implement `public static` method in your util file but you can not use DatePipe in that. So I would suggest use `moment js` . You can find demo by below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-broavc?file=src%2Fapp%2Futils.ts

Comment: Keval, I found the issue. It looks like I have to do some async await otherwise it returns an error on the console, since Im trying to render before I get the value from convertDate in your example.

Comment: Can you please modify my answer with your working code. @pvg1975
So that others can find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are just creating utility functions** that doesn't depend on the current state of your app, then you can simply export each function from a `ts` file.

Create a `date.util.ts` file, and export all your functions

```
export function dateFormat(myDate, format) {
    let temp=this.datePipe.transform(myDate, format)
    return(temp)
  }
```

Now you can import the function in your component files:

```
import * as DateUtil from './utility/date.utils';
...
DateUtil.dateFormat()
```

For better folder structuring, I usually create a utility folder with an `index.ts` file that exports all the utility functions.
**Advantage - Tree shaking**. All the unused functions will be not making their way into the final bundle.

**When your functions modify the state of the app:**

If you need to save the state of the app/component- you should create `services` and inject them into your component files.
Read more about creating services [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-services-in-angular-application/)

Comment: Hello Pankaj. Thanks! Im getting "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected." at the export sentence (?)

Comment: Is the dateFormat function inside of a class? If yes, then you need to export that class instead of the function. In my example, I assumed that only functions are there.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to store several functions on one file, import that file and call the functions from other components is simply `service`.

Suggestions:

1. Use Angular Service
2. Use Angular Date Pipe -> It can be customized in a wide variety
3. If you still insist on using this function, just use a single line: `return this.datePipe.transform(myDate, format)`

Comment: Its for several functions, one of them to check if an email is valid. That one Is just an example :)

Comment: Then service would be the good choice. You can name it like core service or util service.